# Using Ruby, not JRuby, in JMS queue?

Tags: ruby, jms

What is the easiest way of pushing a message to a JMS queue (hosted by Tibco EMS) using Ruby, not JRuby?

Comment: Is STOMP an option? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/STOMP/StompConnect

Comment: thank you Dave, i guess that's best answer i have, could you make it as  answer not comment, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2):

[Stomp](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/STOMP/Home) is a mechanism that allows [arbitrary clients](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/STOMP/Clients) to attach to Stomp message brokers. [StompConnect](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/STOMP/StompConnect) turns JMS providers into Stomp brokers, including Tibco EMS (not Tibco RV).

I'm not sure if this is the absolute easiest; other options would include using Tibco EMS's C++ client and interfacing it using a Ruby FFI mechanism. I don't know which would be the "best".