# How to connect to tibco EMS Queue and send a xml file in Ruby not JRuby?

Tags: ruby, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I want to send the xml file into tibco EMS queue in Ruby. I found the gem "jruby-jms" for JRuby but i need to use Ruby code for this connection. Is there any specific ruby gems available to connect Tibco Queue and send the message?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Anto

Comment: You might want to read this related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330594/using-ruby-not-jruby-in-jms-queue/18057849